# xml schema restriction list with different sub elements by value

Tags: xml, xsd

I like to create an element that has different subelements depending on the value of one of these elements. I wonder if and how I can achieve this (best possible solution).
So if the `Type` is `piece` there must be a `Weight` element. If the `Type` is `kilogram` or `gram` or ... it does not need it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Amounts>
        <Amount>
            <Type>piece</Type>
            <Value>6</Value>
            <Weight>
                <Value>1.5</Value>
                <Type>liter</Type>
            </Weight>
        </Amount>
        <Amount>
            <Type>kilogram</Type>
            <Value>0.610</Value>
        </Amount>
    </Amounts>
```

So I thought I might do something like this, but I get errors (see below).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.test.org/amount"
    xmlns:amount="http://www.test.org/amount" elementFormDefault='qualified'>
    <element name="Amount">
        <complexType>
            <choice>
                <group ref="amount:kilogram" />
                <group ref="amount:piece" />
            </choice>
        </complexType>
    </element>
    <group name="kilogram">
        <sequence>
            <element name="Type" fixed="kilogram" />
            <element name="Value" type="float" />
        </sequence>
    </group>
    <group name="piece">
        <sequence>
            <element name="Type" fixed="piece" />
            <element name="Value" type="int" />
            <element name="Weight">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="Type" type="amount:amountType" />
                        <element name="Value" type="float" />
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </sequence>
    </group>
    <simpleType name="amountType">
        <restriction base="string">
            <enumeration value="kg" />
            <enumeration value="g" />
            <enumeration value="mg" />
            <enumeration value="lb" />
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
</schema>
```

Error I get at line 5 is:

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>     - cos-nonambig: "http://www.test.org/amount":Type and "http://www.test.org/amount":Type (or elements from their substitution
>   group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation
>   against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those two
>   particles.
>     - cos-element-consistent: Error for type '#AnonType_Amount'. Multiple elements with name 'Value', with different types, appear in the model
>   group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you made "Type" an attribute rather than an element, then you could do it in XSD 1.1 using conditional type assignment. Otherwise, sorry, you're out of luck.

Comment: Hmm okay, could you give a short example how to do it in XSD 1.1? I'll try it later and check your answer then.

Comment: Priscilla Walmsley has a number of examples of conditional type assignment here: http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/chapter14.html (if you want to understand them properly, buy her book!)